# How to use a dynamic comma separated String value as input for a List()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm building a Spark Scala application that dynamically lists all tables in a SQL Server database and then loads them to Apache Kudu.

I'm building a dynamic string variable that tracks the primary key columns for each table. The primary keys are comma separated within the variable. The following is an example of my variable value:

```
PrimaryKeys=storeId,storeNum,custId
```

The following is a required function that I must enter a `List[String]` as input (which primary keys is definitely not correct):

```
setRangePartitionColumns(List("storeId","storeNum","custId").asJava
```

If I just use the `PrimaryKeys` variable for the `List` input (like the following), it only works for a single column (and would fail in this example with 3 comma separated values):

```
setRangePartitionColumns(List(PrimaryKeys).asJava
```

The following is another example, but using a `Seq()`.  I"m supposed to put the same Primary Key column names in the same format below. Manually typing the column names works fine, however I can not figure out how to dynamically input the variable values:

```
kuduContext.createTable(tableName, df.schema, Seq(PrimaryKey), kuduTableOptions)
```

Any idea how I can parse the variable `PrimaryKey` dynamically and feed it into either function regardless of the number of comma separated values included?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `val valuesAsList = "storeId,storeNum,custId".split(",").toList` that will give you `List("storeId", "storeNum", "custId")` - [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) - [First google result to _"Scala split String in List"_](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-split-string-example).

Comment: The sad thing is that I had been googling for hours.... as I mentioned I'm new to very new to Scala.... thanks very much for your assistance.

Comment: Despite my apparent ignorance, you helped me complete the finishing touches on a PoC Scala application that loads an entire SQL Server database into Kudu dynamically... thanks so much!